# Magnolia Mail Module Doesn't Work

Tags: magnolia

Im trying to send an email using Mail Module in Magnolia CMS 4.5.4. The code I have so far is:

```
    protected void sendEmail(CommentDTO comment){
        if(comment!=null){
            try{
                MgnlMailFactory mailFactory = MailModule.getInstance().getFactory();
                if(mailFactory!=null){
                    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();


                    MgnlEmail mail = mailFactory.getEmailFromTemplate("MyTemplate", params);
                    mail.setToList("whoever@whatever.co.uk");
                    mail.setBody("HELLO");
                    mail.setFrom("whoever@whatever.co.uk");
                    if(mail!=null){
                        MgnlMailHandler mmh = mailFactory.getEmailHandler();
                        if(mmh!=null){
                            mmh.prepareAndSendMail(mail);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

The log I get is:

```
2013-02-22 16:52:30,357 INFO  fo.magnolia.module.mail.handlers.SimpleMailHandler: Mail has been sent to: [2013-02-22 16:52:30,357 INFO  fo.magnolia.module.mail.handlers.SimpleMailHandler: Mail has been sent to: [whoever@whatever.co.uk]
```

But the email never come...

Before this trace I get :

```
2013-02-22 16:52:24,212 WARN  info.magnolia.cms.util.DeprecationUtil            : A deprecated class or method was used: Use IoC!. Check the following trace: info.magnolia.module.mail.MailModule.getInstance(MailModule.java:80), info.magnolia.module.mail.MgnlMailFactory.getEmailHandler(MgnlMailFactory.java:69), the full stracktrace will be logged in debug mode in the info.magnolia.cms.util.DeprecationUtil category.
```

Eclipse marks the method MailModule.getInstance() as deprecated but I have no idea what I must to put instead.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solve it with this code:

```
protected void sendEmail(CommentDTO comment){
    if(comment!=null){
        try{
            MgnlMailFactory mailFactory = MailModule.getInstance().getFactory();
            if(mailFactory!=null){
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("articleName", comment.getArticleName());
                params.put("id", comment.getId() );
                params.put("commentText", comment.getComment());
                params.put("author", comment.getName());
                MgnlEmail mail = mailFactory.getEmailFromTemplate("myTemplate", params);
                mail.setBodyFromResourceFile();


                if(mail!=null){
                    MgnlMailHandler mmh = mailFactory.getEmailHandler();
                    if(mmh!=null){
                        mmh.prepareAndSendMail(mail);

                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error sending email: " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I think what it make it works was this line:

```
mail.setBodyFromResourceFile();
```

And, of course, a good configuration of the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

As there are no thrown Exceptions, I guess you wrongly configured your SMTP server or not at all. How to do this can be read here: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/modules/mail.html#ConfiguringSMTP

Also, assure that:

- Your mail didn't land in any spam filter (maybe outside your mailbox)
- There are no blocking firewalls (e.g. when running on localhost)