# Magnolia form module templates are missing in new page wizard

Tags: magnolia

I'm building a site starting from the magnolia empty webapp with maven. 
All is ok but now I'm now writing the contact page of the site. I'd like to use the magnolia mail module for this. So I installed the mail module and the form module.

Problem:

After installing the form module in magnolia 5.4, the template called "Form" does not appear in the template selection when creating a new page in the pages app.
As it seems from the Documentation, it should be there.

Details:

Other templates, created by me with yaml and freemarker, correctly appear (and i can use them correctly).

The mail module is up and running and configured: i can send a mail to myself with the "verify setting" page, using a template i made, but i'd like to create a contact module for my site.

I installed the module with maven like:
dependency:   groupId:info.magnolia, artifactId:magnolia-module-form  , version:2.3

and installed it with the usual steps (installed module, wait , correctly completed without messages,  started magnolia)

I DO NOT have STK installed since i'm using MTE... and i've other modules installed (resources, site, mail, MTE, DAM, etc...)

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? :|

Otherwise, Can the magnolia mail module simply be used standalone without the form module to send out a email, may be pointing a hand-written form to somewhere? 
Or, best option imho: can I make a new form template with yaml? I can't find docs about it.

Thank you!.

Edit:  I tried to install the STK along with MTE (I correctly updated to magnolia 5.4.1) but it relies on data-module 2.3.6 (which i don't have in my dependencies and which i don't use) so it won't install the STK.  Also , installing STK just for a form template seems overkill to me. I'd prefere to understand how to insert a form in one of my templates.

Answer (score 0):

Preinstalled templates are for STK. If you want to use Magnolia without STK, then you need to write template yourself, but in exchange have much more freedom in what you can do with that template. Once you create and register template you should be able to use it.

Re STK - latest version doesn't have any dependency on data module - [see module descriptor](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/?p=modules/standard-templating-kit.git;a=blob;f=magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit/src/main/resources/META-INF/magnolia/standard-templating-kit.xml;h=926ad4c7b9bb3b83fe9f499119d5859a99cc92c9;hb=HEAD). Either I'm blind or there is no such dependency. :D

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you.
For me it would be better to make my own html form to send a contact mail through the mail module, but i can't figure out how to do it.
Is there an URL where i have to post the fields which i want to pass to the mail template?
I can send the mail from the admin ui / mail module (in the verify config tab) using my mail template.

Comment: About the STK, cleaned up, added also magnolia-module-legacy-admininterface  5.3 ,  magnolia started, HOWEVER when selecting Form as page template , "edit page" gives the error: 
FreeMarker template error -- 
No error description was specified...
Caused by: info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: Can't render area node /home/contattaci with name htmlHeader
....Caused by: 
org.apache.commons.proxy.exception.ProxyFactoryException: Proxy class cannot extend info.magnolia.module.site.templates.SiteAwareTemplateAvailability, because it has no visible "default" constructor.
lol.. no way :(

Comment: re url for mail module - no, there is no such url, typically you leave action in the form empty so after submit, page is rendered again and in the execute() method of your model you do whatever processing you want (in case of default form model, it would invoke form processors). In your case, you would want to call CommandsManager to get instance of MailCommand, create simple context where you pass all the params from the form, add one for template definition you want to use to render form data, add email address and invoke command with the context.

Comment: The render exception sounds weird. AFAIK TemplateAvailability is called when selecting template for the page, so before you start rendering/editing the page. Would need to see the screenshot and full stack trace ... you will be better of creating issue in Magnolia for that at http://jira.magnolia-cms.com

Comment: HI, at last I uninstalled stk and made a page with a form submitter with Magnolia Mail , based on this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029418/
Not the best thing one could do , but it works.

Comment: I had the same issue today with Magnolia 5.4.1, already posted questions in the wiki (see comments on https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Form+module). Would be great to have a working sample in the new tours demo. Right now I have added the form elements as availableComponents, but don't have any formFields to add to the form, probably due to a missing template? I followed the instructions from Attila in the wiki. Screenshots: http://ibin.co/2DaYXNgHvAAX and http://ibin.co/2DaYnIulKvS1 -> no "add" action available in the actionbar.